# MS Outlook td alignment

Tags: outlook

I have trouble finding what's causing the last td element in my table to be vertically offset in Outlook '07, '10, '13 and '16.

[image]

The last row will always be offset. I tried looking at line heights, heights, widths, line breaks, but to no avail.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the issue was an empty  I used for adding spacing (some clients don't support margins). I used an empty table to for spacing instead (nasty, I know).